# Speed up pd.read_sql

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently creating a Flask application connected to an Azure MySQL database.

Records from the database table are being read into a pandas dataframe, and I am setting the Id column to be the index (where images is a sqlalchemy table). In my situation, a dataframe is required.

```
images_df = pd.read_sql(images.select(), engine, index_col='Id')
```

Although there are only around 200 records, this step is taking anywhere from 3-7 seconds to execute. How can I improve the speed when reading data from a database table to a dataframe? Thanks

Comment: Does this `images` table contain ... images? (Like JPEG, PNG, BMP, or similar?) If so, are they large? How many of them are you retrieving? Approximately how many (mega?)bytes of data are you pulling down from the cloud?

Comment: It just contains urls of images (which are not stored in this database) and some text details. So just an Id column and 2 text columns for each record

Comment: How long does the query itself run, without pandas?